# What is the best (for my budget) instant camera?

Tags: film, printing, fujifilm, polaroid, instant-camera

This might sound a bit silly, but I'm looking to buy an instant camera to be used by guests at my wedding which is in 2 months from today. The idea is to have an instant camera that can be passed around to the guests. They will take their photo and we'll write their wishes (or whatever they want basically) on the photo film. My budget is 300$ :)

**These are the things that I'm looking for:**

- Polaroid-like film (the one with the white border around the pictures)
- Easy to use camera (remember, the guests will be taking their own photos)
- The pictures should be printed in less than a minute

**And some questions**

- Can instant cameras hold more than 10 films at a time? We don't want to change films every 10 photos :)
- Do instant cameras need any replacement parts other than the films?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fuji Instax Wide** is the way to go.

I used it at events and also talked to people using it at weddings, exactly for the same purpose you are planning to use it for.

Impossible Project film develops very slowly. You also should cover it while developing to get the full color. The only advantage of it is that it has the "classic" polaroid frame size. But people don't care about that. the magic is in the process, not the format<sup>1</sup>.
If you want to experiment, Impossible Film is great, but for a wedding you need something a little more reliable.

The Instax Mini is a joke. Not what you want.

> be passed around the guests, they will take their photo

**I do not recommend that.** The camera might end up lying abandoned on some table somewhere. Ensuring that everybody is on at least one image is not an obvious priority to your guests.

A proven strategy is to **have an album, that the pictures are glued into.** That allows people to write something, be creative and leave a very personal note. If you want to keep the instant film action in one place, you could also make a wallpaper, which has the advantage that all guests can read what others have written. But that would kind of defeat the point of having a portable camera that creates instant prints, wouldn't it?

**Assign one person to take care of the instant camera and the album.** He/she should have a check-list of all guests and make sure everybody has a go (if that's important). If the guests start passing the camera around, great! But if they don't, the camera will not start taking pictures on its own. Then **there could be guests that are not able or willing to operate a camera**, like older people for example.

Also, the assigned person is ***that other guy* for group shots**. People are usually together in certain groups and you'd expect to see them in one image. If one member of a group is taking the image, he/she is not in the image, which leads to odd "missing because on the other side of the camera" images. Images of a single person will be rare. Group shots are very common, which makes the wide format actually better suited for this kind of photography.

Then there's the whole management to it. **Who carries the film cartridges? Spare batteries?** Trust me, you want to assign somebody to be the "photographer". Pick somebody who knows most guests and is known by them.

Last but not least, these are not exactly professional cameras. **Predicting the framing of a shot can be a challenge.** Now if the camera is passed around, everybody has their learning experience, read: wasted photos. The assigned camera man or woman can be a default fallback and if guests want to give it a go, he can give them a few hints.

---

<sup>1</sup> There actually is some magic to the wide format. It lends itself very well to group shots, which will probably be the majority of shots. Much better so than the original square polaroid frame.

Comment: Um...forgot your format footnotes?

Comment: @inkista it was sort of an experiment...which failed =) It was more of a cross reference back to the earlier statement that the format doesn't matter (which makes sense in its context), which later in the answer turns out to have a bit of a significance. I clearly over thought this. Does it make sense now? Please edit if it still doesn't.

Comment: wow! your answer covered all my questions!!! Thank you very much for the time you took to give such a long answer. 

There will be one person who will carry the camera around (and all other accessories) Btw, do you know from where i can get the cheapest films for this one? Looking for 80-100 films

Comment: @null Looks great, now! And agree, the wide vs. mini is a big distinction. I still like the printer sol'n better, because you'll maintain a high-quality digital copy if you want to make serious prints/post-process, and the printer can be used with any camera that can do wi-fi/smartphone transfer (I use my SP-1 with my iPhone 5S, X100T, GX-7 and Powershots [via eye-fi card]), so you're not at the mercy of the Instax camera lens but since Fuji doesn't make a printer in the wide format...

Comment: @inkista (with eye-fi not being an option) It's a shame that wireless grips for DSLR cameras are ridiculously expensive. I absolutely agree on the benefits of the printer, in particular the possibility to duplicate an image. If you have a group shot on instant film and everybody involved wants a copy, that's a problem. I guess this is one reason why instant film found this niche use for weddings.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't think you have much of a choice in this arena. Probably the only camera that's going to fit the "instant photo"/polaroid bit of that that you can easily obtain new for a lower-cost  is going to be a Fuji Instax Mini camera--and the prints made are tiny--roughly business-card size. The problem, budget-wise, is going to be the film, and the quality of the images is probably not what you'd like.

You may want to consider getting a Fuji Instax SP-1 printer, and letting everybody use the Instax Share app on their smartphones instead, so they can also have a digital image of higher quality as well as the print (and you typically don't need to teach people how to use the camera in their phone), but you're still going to run bang on into the cost of the film/batteries (it uses a weird CR2 battery, although you can also use smartphone external battery packs with a special cable).

And no, these Instax cameras can only do 10 at a time--that's how many sheets are in the cartridge you load into the camera/printer.

Your only other option, aside from vintage restored Polaroid cameras, is liable to be the Impossible Project's [Instant Lab](https://shop.the-impossible-project.com/shop/instant-lab-universal), but that's pretty close to all of your budget without throwing in the fim.

Comment: Thank you for your feedabk inkista, but from what i understand first you take the photo on your phone, and then connecting it to print the photo. So that would be hard to explain to each person :(

What about other comeras like the Polaroid Z2300 or the instant mini 90. Do they worth the extra money?

Comment: We can't tell you if anything is "worth the extra money" as that's very much a personal question - it has a completely different answer if you're a millionaire or if you're scraping money together to get by every week.

Comment: My wife did her own research and now she wants the Polaroid Z2300 because the films are cheaper than other instant photos ?

Comment: @user2093301 [Zink](https://www.zink.com/content/technology-0) isn't polaroid/instant film tech--it's a special type of thermal printing where temperature-sensitive crystals are embedded in the paper, and the "printer" uses heat to get specific colors. The prints are borderless, and some reviews say the image quality isn't as good as Instax. But yes, the printer paper is cheaper, as it isn't film.

Comment: Thank you inkista. I don't mind going for a lower pic quality if i can get more quantity. Do you know if it can print with white borders to match the real polaroid films?

Answer (score 1):

No instant camera holds more than 10 shots at a time, but reloading is fairly easy.

If you want a Polaroid-like image then you have a few choices:

You could scout around thrift stores, ebay, etc and try your luck at buying an old Polaroid camera, either a 600, Spectra or SX-70 model and then purchase Impossible Project film. Impossible are the only company currently producing integral instant film for old Polaroid cameras.

**Pros:**
Polaroid like image.
Possible inexpensive camera cost (I've found 600 model cameras in thrift stores for around five dollars each).
Impossible film is available in color and black & white. Image size is the same as Polaroid film image size.

**Cons/Considerations:**
No guarantee that the camera you buy is in good working condition. Impossible film is not equal in image quality to the old Polaroid film. Impossible film is expensive, as of this writing it is $23.49 for 8 shots. Impossible film takes longer for the image to fully develop than Instax film.

You could buy a Fuji Instax Wide camera and Instax Wide film. I just looked up an Instax Wide available online from a reputable camera store for $109.00 and film for $15.99 for two packs of 10 shots each.

**Pros:**
Instax cameras and film are currently in production and are available from a large number of sources. Instax wide is somewhat close in size to some of Polaroid Spectra films (Polaroid Spectra film = 73mm x 92mm image size, Instax Wide film = 60mm x 99mm image size. Instax image quality is very good. Instax images develop quickly. Impossible film, like its Polaroid integral film predecessors, contains a battery in the film pack, so the camera does not require batteries.

**Cons/Considerations:**
Instax film only available in color. Camera requires batteries.

You could buy a Fuji Instax Mini camera and Instax Mini film. Currently I see different models of Instax Mini cameras ranging in price from $69.00 - $149.99 and film for $15.88 for two packs of ten shots each.

**Pros:**
Instax cameras and film are currently in production and are available from a large number of sources. Instax image quality is very good. Instax images develop quickly.

**Cons/Considerations:**
Instax film only available in color. Instax mini images are (not surprisingly) quite small, 46mm x62mm. Camera requires batteries.